# ng-resource with custom object + Asp.net web api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, ngresource

ng-resource - could not able to  pass the employee object to web api

### Angularjs code

```
 app.factory("Entry", function ($resource) {          
 return $resource("/api/Emp/",
                { },
                {

                "update": { method: "PUT" },

                "reviews": { 'method': 'GET', 'params': { "id": 1, 'name':        "ram" }, isArray: true },
               "updateEmp": { 'method': 'GET', 'params': { ng: '@id', id: '@id', Employee: '@emp', status: '@status' }, isArray: true }

                }
            );
        });

postData = [{
                "id": 1,
                "Empname": "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy",
                "Address": "Douglas Adams"
            }];

var ent = Entry.updateEmp({ ng: 1, id: 3, employee: JSON.stringify(postData),                                    status: 'test' });
```

### Web API method

Here is the method:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetEmployee(int ng,int id, **Employee employee**,string status)
{
}
```

Can get all the values except Employee(getting null value).Please advise.

Comment: You are calling update from client and on the server side you have `GetEmployee`? It should be `PutEmployee`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to send a single employee, not an array with a single instance.

Try replacing it with this

```
postData = {
                "id": 1,
                "Empname": "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy",
                "Address": "Douglas Adams"
            };
```

Also your `updateEmp` method is expecting a field called `@emp` but you have called it `employee`. Please update that line to the following.

```
"updateEmp": { 'method': 'GET', 'params': { ng: '@id', id: '@id', Employee: '@employee', status: '@status' }, isArray: true }
```

It would also be useful to open the developer console (F12) in your browser and have a look under Network to see the XHR and make sure the request is formed correctly